# Need help finding an api for cost of living related data

Tags: rest, api

I need help finding an api for data related to cost of living. I really have looked around a lot and I need the data to develop my RESTful application. Apis would need to have data on one or multiple of these categories:

Average cost of {x} by city where x is one of the following:

Housing
Gasoline
Utilities
Child Care
Education
Healthcare
Groceries
Property Taxes
Income taxes
Other taxes
Car Insurance
Other Insurance

Comment: @Vaiden I have spent hours looking on google. numbeo charges 220 dollars a month for a basic plan. I am looking for a free api if that is even a real thing.

Comment: @Aaron Loomis, did you found something?

Answer (score 1):

This API might give you the data you need:

[Cities Cost of Living](https://rapidapi.com/ditno-ditno-default/api/cities-cost-of-living1)

It contains detailed information about the living expenses of 600+ cities around the world, including multiple indexes like Groceries, Purchasing Power and Rent.

On a more detailed level, it has average prices (and ranges) of individual items like a specific food, the cost of an apartment or salary.

And you can get the data in a lot of different currencies.